# bootstrap and ms edge bug?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, microsoft-edge

I have create website (bootstrap). On chrome/firefox etc is working but on edge I have problem. [look at this page](http://www.rmonline.com) at bottom part, there are 4 buttons. When they hovered they move and don't get back to normal position. 
I searching online but can't find anything about this error. Or it's my wrong code? What do you think?

Code below

```css
#bottom_fourth_row {
    display: table;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

#bottom_fourth_row [class*="col-"] {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 45px;
    /*display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 45px;*/
}

#bottom_fourth_row>.col-sm-3>img {}

#bottom_fourth_row>.col-sm-3>h3 {
    font-family: avenir_light;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #027a9e;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#bottom_fourth_row>.col-sm-3>h4 {
    font-family: avenir_light;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0;
    color: #7d7d7d;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.3em;
}

#bottom_fourth_row [class*="col-"] button {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 90px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #2aa3c3;
    font-family: basic;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#bottom_fourth_row [class*="col-"] button>a,
#bottom_fourth_row [class*="col-"] button>a:focus,
#bottom_fourth_row [class*="col-"] button>a:hover,
#bottom_fourth_row [class*="col-"] button>a:visited {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
 <div class="row" id="bottom_fourth_row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3"> <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
                            <h3>text</h3>
                            <h4>text</h4>
                            <form>
                                <div class="form-inline">
                                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="list" value="wgPkaIHO7pFCp9G65wvXXw" />
                                    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn">submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3"> <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
                            <h3>text</h3>
                            <h4>text</h4>
                            <button class="btn"><a href="#">more</a></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3"> <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
                            <h3>text</h3>
                            <h4>text</h4>
                            <button class="btn"><a href="#">more</a></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3"> <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
                            <h3>text</h3>
                            <h4>text</h4>
                            <button class="btn"><a href="#">more</a></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Post your relevant code.

Comment: You need to create a [mcve] of your problem here. If you just link a website, nobody will understand what the problem was after you fix it and it will have no value to anyone experiencing the same bug. Besides, from a quick look at it, it looks like you're not familiar with Bootstrap yet and are not paying attention to details when implementing its utility classes. I might be wrong, though.

Comment: Sorry, my error. I add code.

Answer (score 0):

So I found reason why Edge play with me.
In `#bottom_fourth_row [class*="col-"]` 
I remove:

```
float: none;
display: table-cell;
```

and add:

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display:         flex;
```

this help with this problem.

It's interesting that this was only with Edge.